# Why this makefile does not build when change a .hpp file

Tags: makefile

I am having problems with this makefile. I want to each .cpp file get a dependency .hpp   eg: a file main.cpp have a dependency main.hpp

The makefile works well, but when I modify main.hpp, Make is not rebuilding.

Can someone give me a hint. Thanks

```
objetivo=control
objetos=$(shell ls *.cpp | sed 's/cpp/o/')
optimizacion=-O2 -pipe
enlaces=-lncurses -lmenu -lpq -lform -lcdkw
CPP=g++ -std=c++11 -Wall

.PHONY: all clean debug rebuild

all:    $(objetivo)

.cpp.o: $*.hpp
    $(CPP) $(optimizacion) -c $<

debug: CPP += -g
debug: optimizacion=
debug: $(objetivo)

rebuild: clean all

$(objetivo):    $(objetos) 
    $(CPP) -o $@ $(enlaces) $(objetos)

clean:
    -rm *.o $(objetivo)
```

Comment: Using `$(shell ls)` is hugely problematic and your `sed` script is imprecise. You want `$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))`

Comment: Thanks. I will change the shell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not right.  Now the `.o` will be rebuilt whenever the `.hpp` file changes, but it won't be rebuilt when the `.cpp` file changes!

If you want to have two different prerequisites, you have to list them both:

```
%.o: %.cpp %.hpp
        $(CPP) $(optimizacion) -c $<
```

Note that `CPP` is not the usual variable for a C++ compiler; the standard variable is `CXX`.

The reason your first attempt didn't work is that old-style suffix rules don't allow any prerequisites.  See the manual for details.

Comment: You are right! I noted the problem the next day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I replaced the rule .ccp.o to:

```
%.o:    %.hpp %.cpp
        $(CPP) $(optimizacion) -c $*.cpp
```

Now every time I modify the related hpp Make rebuild the matched .cpp

Thanks anyway

Comment: `rebuild` is broken for parallel builds (`-j`), also you don't need to call `shell` to get a list of object files, `$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))` will do the same thing.

Comment: I did not notice the fail in rebuild. You are right. Thanks a lot.